# Android: Disable touch after double tap or long press

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I have created a GestureDetector to detect a double tap or long press. If either of them are triggered, I would like to disable any more touches. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well there could be two ways to do this.
1. you have to implement onTouchListener along with a conditional variable say boolean. declare

```
Boolean isDouble = false; // your activity level variable
```

now when you have detected the double touch or longpress set it to true

```
isDouble = true;
```

now in your onTouchListener .

```
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(isDouble)
                return false;

            }
        });
```

2. Other method may not work properly on some devices but it can work for your case.

   view.setOnTouchListener(null);